# C++ Using Pointers with structures in functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, structure

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to organize a customer’s bank account information using structures and pointers. I am getting an error in the `initialize_CD_account` function.

The error message says "uninitialized local variable 'a' used"

I don't know what the problem is, any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CDAccount
{
    double balance;
    double interest;
    int term;
};

struct CheckingAccount
{
    double balance;
    double interest;
};

struct CustomerInfo
{
    char * first_name;
    char * last_name;
};

struct Account
{
    CustomerInfo * cP;
    CheckingAccount * ckP;
    CDAccount * cdP;
};

void initialize(Account &);
void initialize_customer_info(CustomerInfo *);
void initialize_Checking_account(CheckingAccount *, double, double);
CDAccount * initialize_CD_account(double, double, int);
void update_customer_info(CustomerInfo *);
double calculate_total_balance(Account);

int main()
{
    Account account;

    initialize(account);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The name of the customer is " << account.cP->first_name << " " << account.cP->last_name << endl;
    cout << "The balance in Checking Account is " << account.ckP->balance << endl;
    cout << "The balance in CD Account is " << account.cdP->balance << endl;
    cout << endl;

    update_customer_info(account.cP);
    double total_balance = calculate_total_balance(account);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The name of the customer is changed to " << account.cP->first_name << " " << account.cP->last_name << endl;
    cout << "The total balance is " << total_balance << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void initialize(Account & a)
{
    a.cP = new CustomerInfo;
    initialize_customer_info(a.cP);
    a.ckP = new CheckingAccount;
    initialize_Checking_account(a.ckP, 2000, 0.02);
    a.cdP = initialize_CD_account(1000, 0.05, 5);
}

void initialize_customer_info(CustomerInfo * P)
{
    char * first = new char[];
    char * last = new char[];
    cout << "Enter customer's first name:";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Enter customer's last name:";
    cin >> last;
    P->first_name = first;
    P->last_name = last;

    return;
}

void initialize_Checking_account(CheckingAccount * P, double b, double r)
{
    P->balance = b;
    P->interest = r;
}

CDAccount * initialize_CD_account(double b, double r, int t)
{
    CDAccount * a;
    a->balance = b;
    a->interest = r;
    a->term = t;
    return a;
}

void update_customer_info(CustomerInfo * P)
{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    cout << "Please enter the customer's new first name:" << endl;
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << "Please enter the customer's new last name:" << endl;
    cin >> lastName;
    P->first_name = firstName;
    P->last_name = lastName;
}

double calculate_total_balance(Account a)
{
    double total = 0;
    total = total + a.ckP->balance;
    total = total + a.cdP->balance;
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CDAccount * a;` in `CDAccount * initialize_CD_account(double b, double r, int t)` is just a pointer and no memory allocated for data.

To fix a problem just use something like that:

```
 CDAccount *a = new CDAccount;
```

**EDIT:**

Also you will have a troubles with information update in `void update_customer_info(CustomerInfo * P)` because you are trying to copy `char*` with operator = (this is a bad practice this local arrays that store data in automatic / stack memory).

Just do not use local arrays `firstName[20]` and `lastName[20]`, e.g.:

```cpp
void update_customer_info(CustomerInfo * P)
{
    cout << "Please enter the customer's new first name:" << endl;
    cin >> P->first_name;
    cout << "Please enter the customer's new last name:" << endl;
    cin >> P->last_name;
}
```

or use functions to copy strings (e.g. strncpy() )

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your variable `a` is uninitialized.
You declared it but you did not allocate any memory for it.
You can do this using the `new` keyword:

```
CDAccount *a = new CDAccount;
```

This allocates memory for your object and then sets `a` to be the pointer to that object.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot that no memory is allocated without the new keyword. I appreciate the help!